# Why is this statement is unreachable?

Tags: go, channel

This code is form *the-way-to-go*, I'm confused with the example of channels. Why is the statement after for loop is unreachable and why the func getData finishes without panic when ch gets empty?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)

    go sendData(ch)
    go getData(ch)  

    time.Sleep(1e9)
}

func sendData(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "Washington"
    ch <- "Tripoli"
    ch <- "London"
    ch <- "Beijing"
    ch <- "Tokio"
}

func getData(ch chan string) {
    var input string
    // time.Sleep(2e9)
    for {
        input = <-ch
        fmt.Printf("%s ", input)
    }
    fmt.Printf("finished") // unreachable, why???
}
```

and output:

```
./prog.go:32:5: unreachable code
Go vet exited.

Washington Tripoli London Beijing Tokio 
Program exited.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop:

```golang
for {
    input = <-ch
    fmt.Printf("%s ", input)
}
```

never exits (it loops for ever) so anything following it cannot be reached. To make it reachable there needs to be a way for the loop to end i.e.

```golang
for {
    input = <-ch
    fmt.Printf("%s ", input)
    if input == "fred" {
        break
    }
}
fmt.Printf("finished") // no longer unreachable
```

Note: It is possible that this will still loop for ever (if "fred" is never sent on the channel it will not exit). However this cannot generally be determined at compile time.

A common way of looping with channels is to use `range`; this will exit when the channel is closed:

```golang
for input = range ch {
    fmt.Printf("%s ", input)
}
fmt.Printf("finished") // no longer unreachable
```

> and why the func getData finishes without panic when ch gets empty?

It doesn't exit; it's continues to wait for another value to arrive on the channel. However as per [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

So when your `time.Sleep(1e9)` is done and main exits the go routine running `getData` is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

```
for {
    input = <-ch
    fmt.Printf("%s ", input)
}
fmt.Printf("finished") // unreachable, why???
```

The for loop has no exit condition and no break inside, which means that it will never exit this loop. And that's why the line following the loop cannot be reached.